# LinqToEntitiesDataController MVC 4 Single Page Application - Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

New to SPA MVC4, trying to pass a session variable to LinqToEntitiesDataController from the account controller to identify the user by:

```
                      using (DALEntities db = new DALEntities())
                        {
                            string PHN = (from p in db.Patients
                                          where p.UserName == model.UserName
                                          select p.PHN).First();
                            Session["P"] = PHN;
                        }
```

In the LinqToEntitiesDataController I am trying to use the variable as follows:

```
public partial class DALController : LinqToEntitiesDataController<MyVDC.Models.DALEntities>
    {
        public IQueryable<MyVDC.Models.TestModel> GetTestModel()
        {
            **string phn = (string)Session["P"];**
            return ObjectContext.TestModels.Where(b => b.PHN == phn).OrderBy(b => b.ID);

        }
}
```

I get this Error:

```
The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

Is this the only way, or is there a better method to use the session variables with this controller.

I also tried to use in the account controller:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["P"] = PHN;
```

But I get this error:

```
'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new SessionHttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
    }
}

public class SessionHttpControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public SessionHttpControllerHandler(RouteData routeData) : base(routeData) { }
}
```

Create session support HttpControllerHandler, and route entry this class in Global.asax.

```
    routes.Add("SessionApis",
        new HttpWebRoute(
            url: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}),
            routeHandler: new SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler()
    ));
```

But, I think ApiController is good to use by sessionless. so scalable and REST principle.

LinqToEntitiesDataController route add at Custom AreaRegistration class( DALRouteRegistration class?).
Change scaffolding default area register code.

from

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DAL", // Route name
        "api/DAL/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "DAL" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

to

```
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("SessionDALApis",
        new HttpWebRoute(
            url: "api/DAL/{action}",
            defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "DAL" }),
            routeHandler: new SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler()
    ));
```

How about this?

Comment: Thanks, I still can't pass the variable to the Linq controller because it is a partial class

Comment: Thanks again, I still can't get the session variable using   string phn = HttpContext.Current.Session["PHN"].ToString(); It is still null

Comment: Hummmm.I did...How about sessionState in web.config?

Comment: Don't have any reference in web.confg; should I?

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for your continuing support, still can't get it working.  I think somehow the session variable is not passed from one controller to the other.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea this probrem...Custom HttpControllerHandler class and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session, I can using sessionState.